# Adding a delay between threads while running JUnit test scripts by creating a Thread pool

Tags: java, multithreading, junit, threadpool, executorservice

I am trying to run a JUnit test scripts (basically all test scripts are Selenium WebDriver related ) parallely by using threads, for which I created a thread pool of size using **ExecutorService** below is my code for threadpool creation

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
for (int threadpoolCount = 0; threadpoolCount < classNames.size(); threadpoolCount++) {
        Runnable worker = new ProcessRunnable(classNames.get(threadpoolCount));
        executor.execute(worker);
    }
    executor.shutdown();
    while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
    }
```

Here is my thread implementation which triggers the Junit class

```
public class ProcessRunnable implements Runnable{
private String classNames;
public ProcessRunnable(String className) {
    this.classNames = className;
}

public void run() {
    try {
        Class testcase = Class.forName(classNames);
        JUnitCore.runClasses(testcase);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

The issue which i am facing is although the Threadpool is maintaining a size of 4 threads as initialized , **it executes all the threads at the same time** , which is creating some synch issues when the browser starts . so my idea is to add some delays between thread execution .

Since I am creating a new runnable thread inside the threadpool, I am not sure on how to add a wait or a delay between threads, I couldn't figure this issue . Kindly help me on this , your  help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using Threads if you want execution to be synchronous?

Comment: I am trying to run Junit test scripts parallely , by creating a threadpool of count 4 . I need to add a delay of some seconds between each just to avoid browser related errors ( synch issues when lauching a browser at a same time )

Comment: Correct me if my idea is wrong , also possibly please provide me an ideal solution to implement .

Answer (score 0):

If you want a serial solution (which you may want if you require a delay), use `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`.  Otherwise you could `sleep` the threads like so:

```
Thread.sleep(1000L); //1 second (takes long, not int)
```

or with a value that is incremented based on your threadcount.

A better solution is to use [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.schedule(Runnable)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#schedule%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29).  You submit them with a custom (static or increasing) delay.  Set the core size to 4, and it will behave like a fixed thread pool; from doc:

> While this class inherits from ThreadPoolExecutor, a few of the
>   inherited tuning methods are not useful for it. In particular, because
>   it acts as a fixed-sized pool using corePoolSize threads and an
>   unbounded queue, adjustments to maximumPoolSize have no useful effect.
>   Additionally, it is almost never a good idea to set corePoolSize to
>   zero or use allowCoreThreadTimeOut because this may leave the pool
>   without threads to handle tasks once they become eligible to run.